# Getting two different values for same atribute from a single table in SQL

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

I am having three tables viz. Bids(bid_id,base_price),Customer(customer_id,name,..) and Customer_Bid(customer_id,bid_id,bidding_amount) where customer bids and his bidded amount is stored in Customer_Bid table.
I want to show the details of customer along with his bidded id and the one with highest bid for same bid id.

I have tried to get the customer details but i am not able to show his bidded amount along with the highest bidded amount whish resides in same table.

Plz any one can help me out.
Thanks.

**Edit**  This is the query that was in the comment

```
select cb.bid_id, c.customer_id ,MyBid=cb.total_bidding_ammount
, HighestBid= max(cb.total_bidding_ammount) 
from customer as c
,customer_bidding as cb
,bid as b 
group by cb.bid_id, c.customer_id, cb.total_bidding_ammount
```

Comment: share the query you are using...

Comment: Please show what SQL or code you are using

Comment: My Query:
select cb.bid_id, c.customer_id,MyBid=cb.total_bidding_ammount, HighestBid= max(cb.total_bidding_ammount) 
from customer as c,customer_bidding as cb,bid as b

group by cb.bid_id, c.customer_id, cb.total_bidding_ammount

Answer (score 1):

If you change this:

```
, HighestBid= max(cb.total_bidding_ammount)
```

to something like this:

```
, HighestBid = 
(select max(bidding_ammount)
from customer_bidding
where bid_id = bid.bid_id)
```

You will on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT  cb.bid_id, 
        c.customer_id,
        cb.total_bidding_ammount,
        topbids.customer_id as topbid_customer_id,
        topbid
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_bidding as cb
ON c.customer_id = cb.customer_id
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT cb.bid_id, c.customer_id, MAX(cb.total_bidding_ammount) as topbid
            FROM customer c
            INNER JOIN customer_bidding cb
            ON (c.customer_id = cb.customer_id)
            GROUP BY cb.bid_id
           ) topbids
ON cb.bid_id = topbids.bid_id
```

Comment: You should not have the c.customer_id field in your subquery.  Care to edit your answer before it starts getting down voted?

Comment: @DanBracuk, yeah, I thought he needed also the customer_id of the highest bider, otherwise your answer is better, of course. SHould I leave the answer as is as an "alternative" solution for a slightly different problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.*, b.bidding_amount,
     e.bidding_amount as highest_bid
from customer a
inner join customer_bid b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
inner join bids c on b.bid_id = c.bid_id
join 
    (select * from (
    select bidding_amount,bid_id
    from customer_bid
    order by bidding_amount desc
    ) d group by d.bid_id) e on b.bid_id = e.bid_id
```

Comment: I don't think so.  If you had a "top 1" or "select max" in subquery d, then maybe.